# Unable to write data(class) properly on socket in java(client) and read it on c++(server)

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp

**I am trying to develop a client server model here. Server is written in c++ and client is in java.**

**Now  I have changed few things here to get the desired output.**

**I have tried two methods.**

**FIRST METHOD is as below:**

**I am writing two integer values in ByteBuffer and sending it on socket using write call. Code is as below:**

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);
socket.setReuseAddress(true);

ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);

buffer.putInt((int)11);
buffer.putInt((int)22);

ostream.write(buffer.array());
```

**And i have written a c++ socket code to receive packets on socket but i am not getting desired data. This is the structure below on which i am mapping incoming data:**

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

**When i run my application, i get some garbage value of 4 bytes.Output is as below:**

> Packet Size : 4
>   t.a : 83946924
>   t.b : 1836667692

**I have also checked using linux command tcpdump and i am getting 4 bytes.**

**SECOND METHOD which i have tried is as below:**

```
class Test implements Serializable
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);
socket.setReuseAddress(true);

ObjectOutputStream ostream = new 
ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

Test t = new Test();
t.a = 11;
t.b = 12;

ostream.writeObject(t);
```

**But using this method i am recieving 3 packets instead of 1.Server side output is as below:**

> ================================================
>   Packet Size : 4
>   t.a : 83946924
>   t.b : 1836667692
>     ================================================
>   Packet Size : 28
>   t.a : 83915379
>   t.b : 1953719636
>     ================================================
>   Packet Size : 10
>   t.a : 28792
>   t.b : 2816

**And on tcpdump also i can see there are 3 packets flowing of sizes 4, 28, 10 bytes respectively.**

**Can Anyone please guide me here that how can i send data and receive it on a c++ application and map it on a structure.**

Comment: Do you know what `writeUTF` and `toString` do in Java?

Comment: Not exactly, but as far as i  know about writeUTF, it takes argument in string. So i have used toString

Comment: Where's your c++ code? Have you used wireshark to check the Java code is sending the data you expect?

Comment: Note the default implementation of  `toString` in Java returns the class name and hash code of the object which isn't what you want

Comment: Search and read articles with keywords "marshaling" or "serialization". I think for you it will be better to use some existing library/protocol for such task.

Comment: i am using c++ boost library for socket programming which is working fine when i am sending anything from a client written in c++.

No, I am not using wireshark but a using a linux command tcpdump which shows exact data transfer on network.And i can see that there are two packet flowing on network first one is of 4 bytes and second one is of 15 bytes as i have mentioned on my query above.

Comment: Have you verified the contents of those packets?

Comment: Yes, I have printed the content of the packets. i have mentioned that above in my query

Comment: `writeUTF()` writes a format that only `readUTF()` understands. There isn't a hope in hell that your C++ code will understand it.

Comment: I have also used writeObject. Plus i am writing ByteBuffer for serialization instead of direct object.

Comment: "I don't know what writeUTF does but it writes something, and I know it needs a string so I called toString" - programming by trial and error doesn't usually work - you have to know what the program actually does instead of putting things together that happen to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have a few problems here. The most pressing one is that you don't know what you are actually writing to your socket (according to your comments above), so lets look into that.

Your `Test` class does not have a `toString()` method, so it defaults to the [`toString()` in `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) which outputs:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

In other words: Not the two integers that you want (btw, a simple sanity check would have been just throwing this string through a `println()` and checking the console).

You then hand this off to [`writeUTF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) which does the following:

> Writes a string to the underlying output stream using modified UTF-8
>   encoding in a machine-independent manner.
>
> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
>   writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is
>   the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
>   in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. If
>   no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the
>   total number of bytes written to the output stream. This will be at
>   least two plus the length of str, and at most two plus thrice the
>   length of str.

Which could explain why you get two packets (length + string), though I can't see if this is what you actually get, as I don't know what "t.a : 83946924" means. Perhaps it would be a better idea to put the raw data bytes from the packet into your question in hex format.

Anyway, that is what you do now. As a simple test to see if there is more wrong, or if this is it, you could try to use [`writeInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)) instead:

```
out.writeInt(t.a);
out.writeInt(t.b);
```

> Writes an int to the underlying output stream as four bytes, high byte
>   first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented
>   by 4.

It should be possible to verify with tcpdump if that gets through fine.

Though I would echo the advice from @sklott to go read about "marshaling" and "serialization", because you probably don't want to just write only the raw ints to your stream. Adding some header information or other "start of transfer" information would be a good idea - you could also add some CRC or something to the end, but since you are using TCP that should not be that necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I can't use writeInt function because i want to write the whole object at once.